# Want to use multiple conditions on same field to count the events in Data Studio

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, looker-studio

Want to use multiple conditions on `event_params.value.string` with different `event_param.key`:

I have synced my firebase data to bigQuery and trying to visualize on Data studio.Data looks like this:

[image: data preview]

Now I have `event_params.value.string` field which has all the values as "app" ,"4G", "App_Open","DashboardOnionActivity" and
Event Param Name  field has  values like  : ....,Action,Label

I want to count only those App_Open which has label as DashboardOnionActivity

I was using CASE with when and Then construct as :

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(event_params.value.string, "(?i) App_Open") THEN "1-App_Open"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(event_params.value.string, "(?i)selfie_capture") THEN "2-selfie_capture"
ELSE "0"
  END
```

This gives me the count of App_Open and selfie_capture but I am not sure how to apply 2 conditions as Param Name is different for both one is Action and other is Label

One workaround can be to have separate events as DashboardOnionActivity_App_Open and Others but looking for some efficient usage if any possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by custom query option when adding data from BigQuery(bq) connector to Data Studio:

So as data obtained in bq from firebase is nested.
Need to use unnest() in subqueries to get the values out of it.

So used query in this format in a custom query :

```
SELECT 
  event_date,event_name,event_params,
CASE
    WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM UNNEST(event_params) i where i.value.string_value='App_Open') = 1 AND (SELECT count(*) FROM UNNEST(event_params) i where i.value.string_value='DashboardOnionActivity' ) =1 THEN "1-App_Open"
    ELSE "other"
  END App_status

From <table_name>
```

​where event_params is the struct field.
Let me break down the query and explain :
`SELECT count(*) FROM UNNEST(event_params) i where i.value.string_value='App_Open'` :

This counts the number of 'App_Open' happen in event_params.value.string_value for one event. As there is no duplicate  event_params  so it is [0,1]
Similarly for DashboardOnionActivity which is 0 when it doesn't occur 1 otherwise.

Once this is added as a data source in Data Studio count can be visualized by several charts like bar, inverted bar, scorecard, etc